# check the value with ng-options value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created the normal select box using ng-options. I have the `value` property and `members` array in the object

```
$scope.currentprop = {
    name : "graphFillDirection",
    members : [{
        name : "ttb",
        caption : "Top to Bottom",
    }, {
        name : "btt",
        caption : "Bottom to Top"
    }, {
        name : "ltr",
        caption : "Left to Right"
    },{
        name : "rtl",
        caption : "Right to Left"
    }],
        value : "ttb"
}
```

so i created the dropdown values with `members.name`.and this is my html

```
<select ng-model="currentprop.value" ng-options="value.name for (key , value) in currentprop.members"></select>
```

**Question**

i iterate through members array and i check `name` with `value` property. so if `members.name` is equal to `value` then i should pass the checked index value to ng-model.
In normal javascript we used to like this `currentprop.members.name.indexOf(currentprop.value)`. so this is what i need to assign to ng-model.
currently i using `currentprop.value` in `ng-model`. In this place i should use index value of checked value.
i dont know how to achieve it. please help me. Thanks in advance. [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KtHUCt?p=preview) here

Comment: I have updated your plunker,  Please check it

Comment: i didnt get the plnkr please send the link

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/wUm0sg63RTzbSGCw2ORm?p=preview or you can replace the select statement with my below code

Answer (score 1):

Try `ng-selected`

```
<select ng-model="currentprop.value" 
  ng-options="value.name as value.name  for (key,value) in currentprop.members" 
  ng-selected="{{currentprop.value == value.name}}">
</select>
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/71qJrIdn82vWbG6MOadR?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, the problem is with ng-options.  I think what you are looking for is this:

```
ng-options="member.name as member.caption for member in currentprop.members"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="value" ng-options="value.name as value.name  for (key,value) in currentprop.members" ng-change=chk(value)></select>
```

To compare when your select an value

```
$scope.chk=function(data)
{
console.log(data== $scope.currentprop.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/R9zFHhXxTFqHGPgN0n4K

I made some small changes and added an ng-change element that will check whether the selected value equals your defined value.

```
<select ng-model="currentprop.selected" ng-change="onDropdownChange()" ng-options="value.name as value.name for (key , value) in currentprop.members">
  <option value="">Choose one...</option>
</select>

$scope.onDropdownChange = function(){
    if ($scope.currentprop.selected === $scope.currentprop.value){
       alert("Selected === value");
    }
}
```